# Autoscaling Spot Fleet can't register instances with Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a Spot Fleet with Autoscaling set and a Classic Load Balancer.

Target Metric: Average CPU Utilization 
Target Value: 75

The issue is - when scaling up, the new instances are not being added to the Load Balancer.  
When looking into the "History" tab (on the spot fleet request) I see:

```
registerWithLoadBalancersFailed: Attempt to register instances with
Classic Load Balancer(s) failed: you are not authorized to register to
Classic Load Balancer 'elb-test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure the [IAM Fleet Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/spot_fleet_IAM_role.html) has rights to the `elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer` action. The default AWS managed role looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```